# Trello + Butler, how do you post card info to my api?

Tags: javascript, post, trello

I am trying to use Butler to post a request to my API with card info. Butler looks like this:
[image]

How do I send the card info inside the payload? Butler has variables like {cardname} but how would I set this up to send a request properly?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to send all your data in a JSON format with appropriate Butler variables.

For example, in your payload

`{ "yourKey": "{cardname}" }`

I used variable `{cardname}`, but you can use all other that you need.

The same rules goes for `Headers` if you need some.

Remember that in your code you'll receive data as a plain string inside your request body.